# Store fetch data in variable to access it later

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I'm facing a probably super easy to solve problem regarding fetching.
I'd like to fetch some json datas and store it in a variable to access it later.
The problem is that I always ends up getting undefined in my variable. What's the way to do to deal with that kind of data storing ?

Here's my code.

```
const fetchCities = () => {
      fetch('cities.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        return data;
        });
      }
    let cities = fetchCities();
    console.log(cities)
```

Already looked up for answers but couldn't find a way to do. Thanks !

Comment: You need to return the `fetch` function and also handle the promise with something like `Async/await`. [**Example Code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-xntpkp?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Sending a fetch request takes time, so the `console.log` works before the data arrives.
The best way to deal with fetch is using async functions and await like so:

```
const fetchCities = ()=>{
    return fetch('cities.json');
}

async function main(){
    try {
        const res = await fetchCities();
        const data = await res.json();
        // handle the data here, this will work only after the data arrival
        console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
main();
```

**Note:** `await` can only be used in async functions, that's the main purpose of the main function.
Or if you want to use `.then`:

```
const fetchCities = ()=>{
    return fetch('cities.json');
}
function main(){
    fetchCities()
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        // handle the data here, all you code should be here
    })
    .catch (err => console.log(err));
}
main();
```

Comment: Thanks I finally used this solution and put all my code in there. Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

You could do this very simply with `async/await` like this:

```js
const fetchCities = async () => {
  let cities = await fetch('cities.json');
  return cities.json();
};

let cities = await fetchCities();
console.log(cities);
```

Comment: await can only be used in async functions

Comment: As of ES2020, [Top-level await can be used in javascript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).